# AngularJs return async factory?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, asynchronous, angular-promise

I've read many answers to this question but I just don't get it. Where does the promise go? I made a simple factory with an async call to a cloud database:

```
app.factory('asyncFactory', function() {

  let toController = function() {

    firebase.database().ref('en').once('value') // get the array from the cloud database
    .then(function(snapshot) { // take a snapshot
      console.log(snapshot.val()); // read the values from the snapshot
      return snapshot.val(); // this returns later
    });

    return 47 // this returns immeadiately
  };

  return {
    toController: toController // why is this necessary?
  }

});
```

I call it from my controller:

```
$scope.words = asyncFactory.toController();
console.log($scope.words);
```

Here's the response:

[image: response]

As you can see, `47` returns to the controller immediately. If I comment out `return 47` then the factory returns `undefined`. Later the async data logs but doesn't return to the controller. I use promises every day but I can't figure out where the promise goes.

Second question: do I need the line `toController: toController` ? Can I get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: The promise doesn't go anywhere because instead of returning it, you're returning 47. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/. Regarding "do I need the line toController: toController", well, no, but then your service would have no method at all, and would be really useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the results from the firebase call in the controller, the factory method needs to return a promise:

```
app.factory('asyncFactory', function($q) {    
  return {
    toController: toController
  };

  function toController() {

    var es6promise = firebase.database().ref('en').once('value');

    var qPromise = $q.when(es6promise)
      .then(function(snapshot) { // take a snapshot
        console.log(snapshot.val()); // read the values from the snapshot
        return snapshot.val(); // this returns later
    });

    return qPromise;
  };

});
```

Because the firebase `.once` method returns an ES6 promise, that promise needs to be brought into the AngularJS framework by converting it to a [$q Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) promise with [`$q.when`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when). Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

In the controller, use the [`.then` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) to extract the data after it returns from the server:

```
var qPromise = asyncFactory.toController();

qPromise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    $scope.words = data;
});
```

The factory function immediately returns a promise. When the data arrives from the server, the data will be placed on `$scope`.

Answer (score 1):

Well toController is eating the promise for itself. ( whenever you call .then(), it means you are waiting for promise), 
Try this

```
app.factory('asyncFactory', function() {
  let toController = function() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
    firebase.database().ref('en').once('value') // get the array from the cloud database
    .then(function(snapshot) { // take a snapshot
      console.log(snapshot.val()); // read the values from the snapshot
      return deferred.resolve(snapshot.val()); // this returns later
    });

    //return deferred.resolve(47) // this returns immeadiately
  };

  return {
    toController: toController // why is this necessary?
  }

});
```

If you don't want this line

> return {
>       toController: toController // why is this necessary?   }

```
app.factory('asyncFactory', function() {

  return {
   var deferred = $q.defer();

    firebase.database().ref('en').once('value') // get the array from the cloud database
    .then(function(snapshot) { // take a snapshot
      console.log(snapshot.val()); // read the values from the snapshot
      return deferred.resolve(snapshot.val()); // this returns later
    });

    //return deferred.resolve(47) // this returns immeadiately
  };

})
```

Comment: My controller is getting "undefined" returned from the factory, i.e., it's not waiting for the async response. But thanks for answering my second question!